# Guards within receive

Tags: erlang

I am having an issue with guards within a receive, since i'm new to Erlang i have read everything i could find on this but nothing that makes it clearer for me.

The problem here is that it never checks the second guard and I don't understand why.

Have I written the guard wrong? is there another way?

```
receive

    {ask, {guessed, N}, User} when guessed < N -> 
        From ! {answer, {wrong, N, lower}},
        main_loop(N, update(wrong, Stats));

    {ask, {guessed, N}, User} when guessed > N ->       
        From ! {answer, {wrong, N, higher}},
        main_loop(N, update(wrong, Stats));       


end.
```

Comment: `guessed` here is an atom not an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might got little confused there.  What are you doing in your guard is comparing atom `guessed` with something received and pattern-matched to `N` variable.  And depending on type on `N` and its value, you will get `true` or `false`.  I guess the `N` is usually some number, and if you [look at comparison in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id78646) and those will always will be smaller than atom `guessed`.

I think that what you are trying to do, is compere received `N` with some value (state) that is kept in given process. Lets call this state `SecretNumber`. Than your `loop` could look like this.

```
loop( SecretNumber )
  receive
      %% neat pattern match, received same number as 
      {ask, {guessed, SecretNumber }, User} ->
          User ! {answer, {right, SecretNumber}},
          ok;  % server will stop (finish)


      {ask, {guessed, N}, User} when N < SecretNumber -> 
          User ! {answer, {wrong, N, lower}},
          loop(SecretNumber);

      {ask, {guessed, N}, User} when N > SecretNumber ->       
          User ! {answer, {wrong, N, higher}},
          loop(SecretNumber)       
  end.
```

So you can see that first receive will execute (will pattern match as we call it) only if we receive same number as the one with which `loop` was called first time.

For other receives, we bind received number to `N` and than compare it to `SecreteNumber` that is kept as process state.

And of course we send back message to `User` (pid) from which we received guess.  So `User` in pattern mach will have assign a value, and to same `User` than we send back a response.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks a million mpm for setting me straight, I got it working directly. Have a great day!